# Hide any application that's outside the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So in this scenario, I have a simple JFrame:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
frame.setSize(screen.width/2, screen.height/2);
frame.setLocation(screen.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2, screen.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

My question is, is it possible for me to open any other application or even use an inter-process communication to be displayed **only** inside my JFrame? For example:

Opening **chrome.exe:**

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("start chrome.exe");
```

**To display like this:**

[image: Example]

Comment: Please clarify your question. A lot, if possible.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Clarifying... How can I display an application **only** inside a JFrame? Like in the picture above?
(Like a virtual machine)

Comment: What is the purpose behind this? Why do you even think that a JFrame can do this? Sorry but this smells of possibly being an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: *"My question is, is it possible for me to open any other application or even use an inter-process communication to be displayed **only** inside my JFrame?"* Thankfully, no. Not in pure Java at least. Should I enter that as an answer?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, I don't think so... I'm trying to simulate an operating system (not with all functions, so I rather start it from the zero), and I'll have two applications, The window (main) one, and other limited apps... for example, Google Chrome. And I want to display it only while it's inside the frame. But whatever, Andrew answered it anyways...

Comment: @AndrewThompson As it's not possible anyways, yeah...

Comment: Yes, you're trying to simulate an OS with the one programming language that is least equipped to do this!

Comment: Java was built specifically to be as OS and hardware agnostic as possible, meaning that it takes pains to remove itself from both OS and hardware, making it the worst possible choice for this sort of project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..is it possible for me to open any other application or even use an inter-process communication to be displayed **only** inside my `JFrame`?

No. Not in pure Java, in any case. To expand on that I'll quote Hovercraft Full Of Eels, who sums it up quite well.

> ..you're trying to simulate an OS with the one programming language that is least equipped to do this! Java was built specifically to be as OS and hardware agnostic as possible, meaning that it takes pains to remove itself from both OS and hardware, making it the worst possible choice for this sort of project

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So you should, given I stole your words & they amount to more characters than my own. (ducks..)

Comment: can I ask which language would be more suitable for this type of job?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with other languages that might be suitable for this type of task. I suspect if it was for Windows only, then .Net would be good, but for multiple OS', C++ might be better.